# Jpa how to return query with many parameters

Tags: jpa

How to optimize this code, now i got only last result from cycle.  toAdd - array with products id.

```
Query query = null;

        for (long l : toAdd) {
           query =  entityManager.createQuery("select p from Products p where p.id =:idProd", Products.class);
             query.setParameter("idProd", l);

        }
        return (List<Products>) query.getResultList();
```

Comment: I think to create a collection before cycle , and at each iteration adding to it the result of query, but i think 
there is a right way to do it without the crutch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're executing the query only once, and at the time you're executing it, the value of its parameter is the last element of your array, since you execute it once you've looped though the whole array.

To fix the code, it should be

```
List<Product> allProducts = new ArrayList<>();
for (long l : toAdd) {
    query =  entityManager.createQuery("select p from Products p where p.id =:idProd", Products.class);
    query.setParameter("idProd", l);
    allProducts.addAll(query.getResultList());
}
return allProducts;
```

But this is very inefficient: it executes a query and thus makes a roundtrip to the database for every ID in the list, instead of executing a single query returning all the products at once. Why not just use a better query:

```
query =  entityManager.createQuery("select p from Products p where p.id in :productIds", Products.class);
query.setParameter("productIds", toAdd);
return query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `IN` clause.

```
query = null;
query =  entityManager.createQuery("select p from Products p where p.id IN :idProds", Products.class);
query.setParameter("idProds", toAdd);
return (List<Products>) query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query = null;

           query =  entityManager.createQuery("select p from Products p where p.id IN(:idProd)", Products.class);
             query.setParameter("idProd", toAdd.toString());

        return (List<Products>) query.getResultList();
```

Where `toAdd.toString()` should generate a coma separated string (e.g `"12,24,45,16"`)